Is Intuition Indispensable in Mathematics?
As a mathematician, I operate as a platonist (as I'm sure most do). I have an intuitive conception of a discrete order of globs or objects starting at some point and continuing off into the distance. I can then extract concepts of the natural numbers from this intuitive feeling. However, I'm aware that when I am practicing mathematics about the natural numbers, I am playing a linguistic game. I postulate a couple observations of how this intuitive natural number structure would behave and then from these axioms formally deduce conclusions. All truth about the objects are epistemologically resting on the axioms I lay as the foundation. This is actually a pretty comfortable place; formalism gives a way to concretize the intuitive feeling of the natural numbers.
It seems like you cannot use formalism all the way down however. Obviously Gödel comes to mind. But even in the act of proving Gödel's theorems, we rely on a finitist number theory of recursive functions. Naturally, we have no reason to doubt the consistency of finite number theory. But how can the result be meaningful if we don't found the result in intuition? That is, the ontology and epistemology of finitistic number theory results are founded in the conception and construction of these concepts in our human brains.
Is this correct? Does the meaning of Gödel's theorems (outside of formalism) have to be founded in intuition? What other ways do philosophers find a way to make meaning out of intuitive mathematical proofs?
It seems like intuition is more foundational than formalism, even though it is much more limited in scope. Then once you found your ontology in intuition you can make meaningful and true statements about formal systems. That is, some formal symbols and objects exist as a mental concept and are conceivable despite being astronomically large and impossible to represent physically in a human lifespan. Then once formalism is established, one can meaningfully perform mathematics as if they were a platonist.

I think the problem is mathematical intuition is not just for intuitionism. The platonists will say they use their mathematical intuition too. Platonists will say that their intuition is not the creation of mental thoughts, but rather a mathematical sense that coincides with platonic/abstract objects. So almost, save for Ed Nelson, all mathematicians use intuition but that doesn’t make them all intuitionists nor make math rest on intuitionism.

The term "intuitionism" has a more technical meaning in philosophy of mathematics, which goes beyond reliance on basic symbol manipulating intuitions. I suspect that many mathematicians would not consider that intuitionism indispensable. However, it is much less controversial, and was Hilbert's view, that formalism does have to be supplemented by some basic quasi-Kantian intuitions, which led to his "finitary means", see Was there a Kantian influence on Hilbert's formalist programme?

Gödel himself was a self-avowed platonist and not a finitist. So, it's kind of strange to surmise that the meaning of his incompleteness theorems would need to be founded in intuitionism with added finitism. Finite objects are also never a problem -- so I find it hard to understand what you're actually asking.

See two dogmas of empiricism from WVO Quine.

I agree with some of the other comments here that one shouldn't conflate intuition with intuitionism. The question would perhaps better be worded as "Is Intuition Indispensable in Mathematics?" Intuitionists would definitely say yes, but others would too. At the end of the day, a capacity to grasp how to reason with abstract objects is necessary for mathematicians. But this does not resolve the question of whether platonism, intuitionism, logicism, formalism, structuralism, or some other philosophical understanding of mathematics is correct.

I submitted an edit to remove erroneous instances of the term "intuitionism", to be replaced by the informal term "intuition". Intuitionism is a pre-established branch of mathematical philosophy, characterized primarily by objecting to the validity of the law of excluded middle. Objections to LEM seem to be completely unrelated to OP's actual question, correct me if I'm wrong. If true, then many posted answers seem to miss the point of the question, due to OP's incorrect use of the term "intuitionism", resulting in a lot of wasted time and effort.

As a mathematician with a few undergraduate philosophy classes under my belt.... I find it hard to think of philosophy of mathematics as something completely detached from epistemology as a whole.  To be sure, it's perfectly reasonable to have a understanding of mathematical knowledge that's refined in a different way from what one might think about other forms of knowledge, but it doesn't make sense to me to have an understanding of mathematical knowledge that is completely detached from one's overall views of what knowledge is.

You may be confusing the concepts of Intuitionism and metalanguage.  It is the latter that - implicitly or explicitly - underpins all work in mathematics and of course especially in logic.  The distinction between metalanguage and object language (or formal language) apparently goes back to Tarski, though it is discussed in logic textbooks less than it should be, with the possible exception of Ebbinghaus's book.
What you describe as "an intuitive conception of a discrete order of globs or objects starting at some point and continuing off into the distance" are metaintegers.
Intuitionism itself does not escape such a dependence on metalanguage.  Ever since Heyting, we have formal systems of intuitionistic logic, and naturally they too have a metalanguage underpinning.
Furthermore, the notion of "finite number theory" is not as self-evident as you seem to think; see for example Hamkins's discussion of the mathematical oracle and whether we have an absolute notion of "finite".
See also this discussion: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/229048/is-platonism-regarding-arithmetic-consistent-with-the-multiverse-view-in-set-the

That dream has now come true :-)  Notice that it is not very different from the idea of the relativity of the concept of set, because if you go from one instance of a universe to another instance of a universe within the multiverse, the notion of "finite" changes.  If you do a simple search on "mathematical oracle" and "absolute notion of finite" you will find Hamkins's comments.  We have written about this as well; see e.g., https://u.math.biu.ac.il/~katzmik/infinitesimals.html#17f @KristianBerry

@KristianBerry - see A question for the mathematics oracle (2012); but it seems to rely on the view that "we have a plurality of set concepts, and our confidence in a unique absolute set-theoretic background is weakened. How then can we sensibly base our confidence in an absolute concept of the finite on set theory? Perhaps this absoluteness is altogether illusory." There is no reason to assume that, for mathematical "finitism", the natural numbers must be grounded on set theory.

@MauroALLEGRANZA, How do you propose to ground "the natural numbers" if not on set theory?  If you wish to ground them on Peano Arithmetic, you run into a similar problem: there is no uniqueness of the model.  This has been known since Skolem (1933).

@MikhailKatz - while "ground" them... Kronecker, Weyl, natural numbers are primitive. Also the basic rules of logic presuppose the possibiliy of iterating an operation.

Natural numbers may be primitive but we still need to know what properties they have, and what axioms they satisfy :-)  When you speak of iterating an operation, you are using metalanguage integers rather than object-language integers.  The distinction is the whole point of my answer.  @MauroALLEGRANZA

My question maybe was a little vague. But you captured exactly what I was talking about with the meta-integers. It seems we cannot escape having intuitive integers as the bottom. My question is more like, what are those meta-numbers and how do we know about them? Brouwer's intuitionism says that those numbers exist as mental constructions in our mind. I don't see any other way to actually point to what a number is except a mental concept that is robust and consistent. Think about the concept "two". It is the same every time you access it.

@BENG Many logicians have come to roughly the same conclusion. Due to Godel, all finite descriptions of the naturals are incomplete, and thus ambiguous. To unambiguously bridge the formalism to the metalanguage, some concept must be taken as primitive. Appealing to sets just moves the ambiguity elsewhere. It's important to note that you can move the ambiguity elsewhere, though. The intuition of the integers as a sequence need not be privileged. For many, "finite set" is more fundamental than "integer", but in the end the two concepts turn out to be equivalent.

No.  Nearly all mathematicIANS rely on intuition, however; despite the stereotype of the pure mathematician being entirely dissociated from reality, nearly all "realized mathematics" is heavily founded in experience.  Where, by "realized mathematics" I mean the subset of "all possible mathematics" (in the Gödelian sense) which Mathematicians have actually bothered to investigate.
Consider, for example, the fact that integers are foundational to like, half†  of any theoretical Mathematics, and you see that our experience in the real world is nearly all of the reason that any theoretical Mathematics is "realized" at all.  To contrast, the set of all provable theorems in just ZFC is, I suspect, significantly larger than the subset of these theorems that include a definition of the integers (15 internet points to anyone who asks MathOverflow to quantify this).  I do not think that our narrow exploration of the set of all provable theorems in ZFC is only a depth thing, in the sense that more theorems need to be built out of increasingly complex combinations of known theorems.  I think that it is also largely a breadth thing, in the sense that many logical statements in ZFC are just not interesting from the point of view of a being living in our universe.
†(no citation, this number is completely fabricated out of thin air)

"significantly larger"? The set of all provable theorems is countably infinite, and the set of all provable theorems concerning integers also -- both obviously have cardinality aleph-0...

@mudskipper fair.  "There exists an $N$ such that for any $n > N$, the set of provable theorems with Gödel number less than $n$ is 'significantly larger' than the set of provable theorems with Gödel number $n$ which include a definition of the integers."  I'm no Metamathematician - go forth to MathOverflow and claim your 15 internet points.

You ask:

Is Intuitionism Indispensable in Mathematics?

No. Mathematics existed and functioned very well before Brouwer introduced intuitionism in mathematics (SEP) and Dummett went after classical logic. What Intuitionism does is introduce proof-theoretic semantics (SEP). From the SEP:

Proof-theoretic semantics is an alternative to truth-condition semantics. It is based on the fundamental assumption that the central notion in terms of which meanings are assigned to certain expressions of our language, in particular to logical constants, is that of proof rather than truth. In this sense proof-theoretic semantics is semantics in terms of proof. Proof-theoretic semantics also means the semantics of proofs, i.e., the semantics of entities which describe how we arrive at certain assertions given certain assumptions. Both aspects of proof-theoretic semantics can be intertwined, i.e. the semantics of proofs is itself often given in terms of proofs.

There's nothing wrong with a Tarskian approach to logic that embraces truth-conditional semantics, but proof-theoretic semantics is a richer model of how humans actually reason. For instance, Martin-Löf’s intuitionistic type theory actually constructs and uses existential quantification as a function of proof. Thus, there are certain ontological advantages in ITT when deciding whether or not the criteria for the existence of non-empty sets are met. This, of course, means that intuitionism carries the seeds of ontological judgement, in the sense familiar to all those clever Germans long before Frege began developing his script. Ultimately, intuitionism as a basis for mathematics seeks, then, to give more flexibility than classic logic allows, and is therefore more in line with a pluralist understanding of how logic functions. But strictly speaking, it's not indispensable.

"Ultimately, intuitionism as a basis for mathematics seeks, then, to give more flexibility than classic logic allows, ... " -- I don't understand your basis for saying this. Constructive proofs -- where possible -- are always better proofs (you don't have to be an inuitionist to accept this) and usually harder to find since they don't allow using certain classical logical axioms.

@mudskipper Proofs are linguistic artifacts of formal semantics. In the abstract, they represent more complex linguistic constructions, so they impose additional costs in terms of devising them. However, using intuitionistic logic is superior than classical logic because, as Brouwer recognized, mathematics is an activity that is primarily adjacent to language, not language; formalism misses the point because it elevates the language of mathematics as the basis, but before there is mathematical form, there is mathematical thought, and this speaks to the empirical experience of the thinker...

Just as the LoT hypothesis fails to capture thought as representations, which are far wider than propositions and their assertoric force, so too does narrow mathematical formalism fail to explicate on the origins of mathematical thinking, arguably the adaptation of more primitive cognitive representations and processes which are a function of our embodied minds. Formalism misses the mark by making language the Golden Calf, and Platonism misses the mark with Magical Thinking. Intuitionism, as Brouwer claims puts math where it belongs, between our ears and before our toungues. Mathematics...

is primarily empirical in its origins, a fact recognized by Mill and Quine. If Pierce is right that mathematics is more about the logic than object, and human reason is defeasible, then logical pluralism and intuitionistic logic affords us the best description of mathematics as experience, rendering it far more consilient with a naturalized epistemology than all other views. Isn't there a more defensible view? @mudskipper

@mudskipper Oh, and this is Where Mathematics Comes From, btw.

Hm -- Thanks for the link, I'll check it out. Btw, not sure if we're talking at cross purposes here. Constructive proofs are the kind of proofs that intuitionists ask for (and try to give).

@mudskipper As you have already conceded,  constructivism is a methodology divorced from questions of metaphysical realism. Intuitionism is an orientation towards the latter.
